# change type in polymorphic association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to rails and I'm using rails Polymorphic association and I ran into a problem
I have two models EmployeeTable and ProductTable. Both have some picture in Picture Model

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end

class EmployeeTable < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
end

class ProductTable < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
end
```

there are two column in Picture  imagable_id and imagable_type. When I create an entry in table it stores imagable_type as either "EmployeeTable" or "ProductTable". Can I change these name to any different Names like "employee" and "product".

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it hard to rename model names, Update model names not to have `Table`?, Its not standard model naming convention in rails.

Answer (score 1):

To retreive the image_type without with table, you can add this method in your model. Changing the assosiated model name while saving will cause issues while querying

```
def neat_imageable_type
   self.imageable_type.gsub("Table", "").downcase
end
```

Comment: but @employee.pictures always look for imagable_type => EmployeeTable

Comment: okay i updated my answer with getter of `imageable_type` with table. wiill that help.?

Comment: i would suggest that remove `table` from the assosiated model table_names. this wont help you will fetch from imagable

Comment: It is just a sample.  Actual models have different names

Comment: okay can you do this. that leave imageable_type as it is and add a method in image model which will return you the name of Imagebale type without table.?

Comment: just updated my answer that where ever you want to show imageable type without table call this method like this : `EmployeeTable.last.imageable.neat_imageable_type` this will return you the type with table bcoz you cannot set the type with different class name